# Preventing Mathematica from applying product rule

Tags: vector-calculus, fluid-dynamics

I am programming viscous terms of compressible Navier-Stokes equations

```
U = {u[t, x, y, z], v[t, x, y, z], w[t, x, y, z]};
a = Div[\[Mu][x, y, z]*(Grad[U, {x, y, z}] + Transpose[Grad[U, {x, y, z}]]), {x, y, z}];
```

Now, I want to prevent Mathematica from expanding the product rule. In other words I want to have

```
a = {d/dx( ... ) + d/dy( ... ) + d/dz( ... ), 
d/dx( ... ) + d/dy( ... ) + d/dz( ... ), 
d/dx( ... ) + d/dy( ... ) + d/dz( ... )}
```

Can you help me out with that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: use a new name e.g. "ddx"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Inactive[Div]` instead of `Div`. When you are ready to evaluate the differentiations, use the substitution `/.Inactive[x_]->x`.

Comment: You could also use `Activate` instead of a replacement rule to get rid of the `Inactive` wrappers